# C# - Call GC.Collect() manually (Disable background GC)

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I want to compare performance between my garbage collection at C++ and C#'s. It is possible to call `GC.Collect()` manually? (I want to run it at specific moments.)

Comment: Can you clear you question. Why do you thing it not possible , it just a method call after all.

Comment: Have you tried calling `GC.Collect`?

Comment: @MichaelT There is a thread that runs it every 850ms. I want to disable it and run this method when I wish.

Comment: Don't go there.  There is a way to disable garbage collection at critical moments.  Don't allocate anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to disable the garbage collection in C# outside of using unsafe code. You *can* force the garbage collector to run by calling `System.GC.Collect()` or one of its various overloads.

Full MSDN Documentation: http://goo.gl/gc7mQ

Comment: There is no a way to collect when I want?

Comment: As stated, you can force the garbage collection to run by calling `System.GC.Collect()`, but that's simply activating it before it decides to step in.

Answer (score -1):

You can trigger the disposal of one specific class.
A class that has `IDisposeable` implemented and runs in `using` context will be disposed when the `using` context exits.

    `MyLogger logger = new MyLogger("time.dat");
    logger.log("before using");
    using (MyDisposableClass myClass = new MyDisposableClass())
    {
        logger.log("before execution");
        myClass.doingSomething()
        logger.log("after execution");
        logger.log("before dispose");
    }
    logger.log("after dispose");`

This is factually wrong - see comment.

Comment: `Dispose()` is used to make sure that *unmanaged* resources are properly released. All managed resources (even in a using block or in an `IDisposable` class) are still subject to garbage collection.